# google analytics look up source

Tags: google-analytics

I use Google Analytics, but can't figure out exactly what it is doing.  It seems like it uses a session id to track where the user goes from.  My question, from my webpage is there a way to use google analytics to look up where the user came from?  Suppose someone gets to my website using Yelp.  Can I query or lookup Google analytics that the user came from Yelp?

One way I could do it is make the yelp url be completesolar.com/?source=yelp, but I don't want to reinvent what google analytics has.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics, navigate to the Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Source/Medium report. From there, you can search for "Yelp".

If you are looking for those who reach your site through an organic search through Yelp, the Medium should be "organic" and Source should be "Yelp".

Comment: I'm interested in grabbing the value from my webpage so that I can submit that information to my crm.  Or imagine if I just want to display a banner on the page that says "Thank you for visiting our site from Yelp.com"

Comment: hm depends on the CRM and what data input it can take. You can create a custom segment in GA with source="Yelp" and feed that into the CRM. Your segment can be referenced by either name or id https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/